# Emacs org-mode babel code color highlight doesn't work in the huge file

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, org-mode

I am enjoying the org-mode org-mode babel code color highlight.
I write HTML, Perl, css and js in a single file and the coloring works fine with each languages' mode.

```
This is the org file with some codes.

#BEGIN_SRC perl
print $perl_code_coloring_works_fine;
#END_SRC

#BEGIN_SRC HTML
<h1>HTML coloring works fine</h1>
#END_SRC
```

But if the.org file exceeds 1,000 lines, the coloring won't work file.
Sometimes the code will turn gray.
(The colors will be reverted if you scroll up and down)

For the workaround, I divided the files but I don't want to do it.
Is there any way to rescue this situation?
(To specify the buffer memory size or something like that?)

Thank you.

M-x emacs-version:
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTX+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian

M-x org-version
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4592

$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-TB4M341 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Aug 25 23:20:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/